# Why use polymorphism when there is inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

I have this code that prints

radio.read()radio.write()

and I'm not using polymorphism. My question is that if the can do this kind of behavious by just using inheritance why to use polymorphism at all???

```html
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class port{
 public:
  
  write(){
   cout<<"prt write()";
  }
  read(){
   cout<<"port read()";
    
  }
  
  
};

class a:public virtual port{
 
 public:
  read(){
   cout<<"a read()";
  }
 
};


class b:public virtual port{
 
 public:
  write(){
   cout<<"b write()";
  }
 
};


class radio:public a,public b{
 
 public:
  write(){
   cout<<"radio write()";
  }
  read(){
   cout<<"radio read()";
    
  }
};


int main(){
 radio r=new b();
 
 
 r.read();
 r.write();
 
 
 return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't separate in that you need inheritance to use polymorphism.

Polymorphism comes in when more than one class inherits from the same base. You can use it to allow you to write code where you refer to objects using the base (by reference/pointer) and those objects can be of any of the derived types.

For example if you derive square and circle classes from class shape, you can write code that works with shapes rather than specifically with either derived class - but can call code via the base interface that behaves differently in each derived class.
Shape might have a GetArea virtual function, Circle and Square both implement this differently. Some function GetTotalArea could iterate over a collection of shapes and call GetArea on each shape. In the future you could add a new class called Triangle and the GetTotalArea function could continue to work without the need for edits (if you'd written it well)

Sometimes though you don't need polymorphism and in those cases yes - you might use inheritance but not polymorphism.